# Using collection_select in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubymine, scaffolding

I have reviewed posts on this board and Google's search results on undefined method `merge' and undefined method`delete' for the same variable in my project.

I have these relationships implemented in the corresponding models

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :diagnostic_code
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end

class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end
```

Currently, I am trying to implement a collection select that will allow the user to select a physician and patient in the appointment creation process.  The error I am currently receiving is:

**undefined method `physician_id' for #**

The error is below.  This error is located in my appointments/form and is encountered when my program attempts to render a new form.

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :physician_id %><br>
      <%= f.collection_select :physician_id, @physicians, :id, :full_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :patient_id %><br>
     <%= f.collection_select :patient_id, @patients, :id, :full_name2 %>
   </div>
```

I have scaffolded each of these fields correctly from my understanding and have copied and adjusted the code that has worked for other users experiencing this problem. I have also ran a migration afterwords.

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with collection_select. The problem is with your f object. Please provide a screenshot of the error. The name of the class is missing in the error information you provided. You are using collection select right though.